# Проблема с возвращением значения функции

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++

```
 using namespace std;

 double funcFind(int n, double a, double b, double step, FuncType f)
 {
 double eps = 0.0000001;
 double min = 0;
 for (double i = b; i >= a; i -= step)
 {
    double pr = ((f(i + eps, n) - f(i, n)) / eps);
    if (pr == 0)
    {
        min = pr;
    }
 }
 return min;
 }
```

Почему переменной min не присваиваются другие значение и всегда возвращает 0??

Answer (score 2):

Ну что ж. Давайте посмотрим.
Вы инициализируете `min=0` `double min = 0;`.
А потом меняете ее значение на `pr` тогда, когда `pr` равно `0` => меняете `min` на `0`.

```
    if (pr == 0)
    {
        min = pr;
    }
```

Больше вы ничего не делаете со значением этой переменной.

Comment: Более того, для любой хоть сколько-нибудь нетривиальной функции pr никогда не будет равен нулю

Comment: ну мне нужно найти минимальный корень первой производной, по идее оно же должно быть равно 0